# Firebase 'signInWithEmailAndPassword' and 'isNewUser'

Tags: react-native, firebase-authentication

I'm currently working on authentication using Firebase's `signInWithEmailAndPassword()`.

I want to check if a user logins in for the first time and recently found `isNewUser`.

The problem is, it always returns false because `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` runs in first place, making `isNewUser` false automatically.

Note) I don't use `createuserwithemailandpassword()` for registration. I manually make an account and provide it to the user.

Any suggestion?

```
firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(user => {
               if (user.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser) {
                    // Want to redirect to Terms of service
                    // But it always returns false
               }})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a new user account with `createUserWithEmailAndPassword ()` that user is immediately signed in. That is the only time when `additionalUserInfo.isNewUser` will be true.

---

I just noticed that you create the account out-of-bounds without calling the API. I'd still expect this same reason to be true though. You should be able to verify that through [`UserMetadata`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.UserMetadata), which you can get from the `User` object.